# get event of ul li javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, parent, children

I have a problem of access to certain class, because I've a list that descent of data base and when I select an item, select all.¿Why?

I think that I need acces with the event.

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#contenedor_central .boton_opciones").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     if ($("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").hasClass('desactivado')){
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").css({"display":"table"});
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").removeClass('desactivado');
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").addClass('activado');
     }else{
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").removeClass('activado');
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").removeClass('activado');
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").addClass('desactivado');
     }
});
```

});

This script show all ul and I want only the clicked element to be shown

This is the php:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="contenedor_central" class="contenedor_central">';
$conexion=mysqli_connect("***", "***", "", "***");
if(!$conexion){
    echo "La conexion ha fallado : " . mysqli_error();
    exit();
}
$tamano_paginas=6;
if(isset($_GET["pagina"])){
    if($_GET["pagina"]==1){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        $pagina=$_GET["pagina"];
    }
}else{
    $pagina=1;      
}
$empezar=($pagina-1)*($tamano_paginas);
$consulta="SELECT * FROM contenidoblog";
if($resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){
    $num_filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    $total_paginas=ceil($num_filas/$tamano_paginas);
}
$consulta_filtrada="SELECT * FROM contenidoblog LIMIT $empezar, $tamano_paginas";
$resultado1=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_filtrada);
    if($resultado1){
        while($registro= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado1)){  
            echo "<div class='opciones'>
                    <ul class='menu_noticia desactivado'>
                        <li>Favoritos</li>
                        <li>Compartir</li>
                        <li>Me gusta</li>
                        <li>Comentar</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>";
            echo "<div id='cajaContenedor'> ";  
            if($registro['imagen']!=""){
                echo "<img src='imagenes/" . $registro['imagen'] . "'  />";}
            echo"<div id='contenedor_titular_cabecera'> <i id='btnn' class='boton_opciones fa fa-bars fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            <a href='*'".$registro['cabecera']."&id=".$registro['id']."'>";
            echo "<p> ". $registro['fecha'] ."</p>";
            echo "<H2>" . $registro['cabecera'] . "</H2>";
            echo "<p>". $registro['titular'] . "</p>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    for($i=1;$i<=$total_paginas;$i++){
        echo "<a href='?pagina=". $i . "'/>" . $i . "</a>  ";
    }
    echo "<BR></BR>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Lfe.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Re *"this is the code php"*: Show **code**, not *pictures* of code. And for a client-side browser question, quoting PHP code is not useful; instead, quote the HTML it generates.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia")` will choose all the li.

You have to distinguish between your current click li.

You can add eventListener for all the `$("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia")` and use `$(this)` to choose your current click li.

```
$("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia).click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if ($(this).hasClass('desactivado')){
    $(this).css({"display":"table"});
    $(this).removeClass('desactivado');
    $(this).addClass('activado');
 }else{
    $(this).removeClass('activado');
    $(this).css({"display":"none"});
    $(this).removeClass('activado');
    $(this).addClass('desactivado');
 }
})
```

Comment: can you show me how to do it with an example please?

Comment: An example is added to the answer @Dj SoundWay

Comment: Ok,I have not expressed myself well. Not working because I have an icon, and the "this" points to the icon,and when I clicked show or not show the icon,  and I want that the "this" points the ul and show ul